# Get number in front of first occurrence of a character

Tags: php, string, text-extraction, truncation

I have this:

```
15_some_text_or_numbers;
```

I want to get what's in front of the first underscore.
There is always a letter directly after the first underscore.

Example:

```
14_hello_world = 14
```

Result is the number `14`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get everything after a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405493/get-everything-after-a-certain-character)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is *always* a number in front, you can use

```
echo (int) '14_hello_world';
```

See the entry on [String conversion to integers in the PHP manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Here is a version without typecasting:

```
$str = '14_hello_1world_12';
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '_'));
```

Note that this will return nothing, if no underscore is found. If found, the return value will be a string, whereas the typecasted result will be an integer (not that it would matter much). If you'd rather want the entire string to be returned when no underscore exists, you can use

```
$str = '14_hello_1world_12';
echo str_replace(strstr($str, '_'), '', $str);
```

As of PHP5.3 you can also use `strstr` with `$before_needle` set to true

```
echo strstr('14_hello_1world_12', '_', true);
```

*Note: As typecasting from string to integer in PHP follows a well defined and predictable behavior and this behavior follows the rules of Unix' own `strtod` for mixed strings, I don't see how the first approach is abusing typecasting.*

Comment: but sometimes there is also a number after, like "14_hello_world22", would this work then?

Comment: You don't need to use substr(). Just use the function strstr(). It returns all characters from first occurrence of the needle (character in this case) till end of the string

Comment: @DPC "all characters from first occurrence of the needle (character in this case) till end of the string" is not what was asked for. If you want to use strstr you have to use the $beforeNeedle flag as show in my answer.

Comment: @Gordon I know. I was just telling the functionality of that function. The readers should at least do some digging work on their own :P

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_match('/^(\d+)/', $yourString, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will hold your value

Comment: Are you sure about `[1]`? I'd say it would be `[0]`

Comment: I'm sure. `[0]` will hold the whole matched string, while `[1]` will have first group value (parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than a regex:

```
$x = '14_hello_world';
$split = explode('_', $x);
echo $split[0];
```

Outputs 14.

Comment: The result can be checked for numerical value using is_numeric($split[0]), and you should set the limit to 2 in explode, because you do not need the rest, and check for $split not being an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

[Demos](https://3v4l.org/ZYCR4)

- I prefer `sscanf()` because it is explicit in its behavior -- it isolates the leading digits and casts the returned value as an integer.

  ```
  echo sscanf($string, '%d')[0];
  ```

  Or

  ```
  sscanf($string, '%d', $integer);
  echo $integer;
  ```
- Casting to an integer is an implicit operation which I also sometimes use in applications.  Like `sscanf()`, this technique will retain the negative sign before a number as well (as a fringe consideration).

  ```
  echo (int) $string;
  ```
- `preg_replace()` is a direct approach and reliable, but the output value will not be cast as an integer, capturing negative integers will require pattern adjustment, and your dev team will need a minimum understanding of regex.

  ```
  echo preg_replace('/^\d+\K.*/', '', $string);
  ```
- `preg_match()` requires a very simple pattern, but creates an array before the desired string can be accessed. Negative integers must be adjusted for.

  ```
  echo preg_match('/^\d+/', $string, $m) ? $m[0] : null;
  ```
- the following techniques rely on the existence of a known character immediately after the desired value. If there is no static character to leverage, the following will be unsuitable.

  ```
  echo strstr($string . '_', '_', true); // append an underscore to the input if not guaranteed
  ```

  And

  ```
  echo explode('_', $string, 2)[0]; // the limit parameter prevents needeless explosions
  ```

  And

  ```
  echo strtok($string, '_');
  ```