# How to get everything after a certain character?

Tags: php, string

I've got a string and I'd like to get everything after a certain value. The string always starts off with a set of numbers and then an underscore. I'd like to get the rest of the string after the underscore. So for example if I have the following strings and what I'd like returned:

```
"123_String" -> "String"
"233718_This_is_a_string" -> "This_is_a_string"
"83_Another Example" -> "Another Example"
```

How can I go about doing something like this?

Comment: If you're using Laravel, the Str::after or Str::afterLast function may be used. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-after

Answer (score 452, accepted):

The [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) finds the offset of the underscore, then substr grabs everything from that index plus 1, onwards.

```
$data = "123_String";
$whatIWant = substr($data, strpos($data, "_") + 1);
echo $whatIWant;
```

---

If you also want to check if the underscore character (`_`) exists in your string before trying to get it, you can use the following:

```
if (($pos = strpos($data, "_")) !== FALSE) {
    $whatIWant = substr($data, $pos+1);
}
```

Comment: What would be the best what to check if the underscore exists, e.g its optional.

Comment: @JohnMagnolia: Then you can just use `if (($pos = strpos($data, "_")) !== FALSE) { $whatIWant = substr($data, $pos+1); }`

Comment: @JohnMagnolia Or a little fancy one-liner: `substr($data, (strrpos($data, '_') ?: -1) +1)`.

Comment: @flu I think you meant to say, harder to read. IMO, less lines does not mean fancier.

Comment: This function will return string after some substring/char or false if needle is not found:
`function StrAfterStr($S, $H) {
  return (($P = strpos($S, $H)) !== false) ? substr($S, $P + 1) : false;
}`

Comment: How would i modify this code to say fetch from a certain position 'n' upto an specific character '-'. For example: the string is "A: hello B: world | bye ;" how can i fetch the keyword 'world' (or any other sentence in that place ) knowing that it will always occur between 'B:' & '|' ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This will handle your specific case (http://codepad.org/4mB9YhvM) The gist is that you find the position of your starting marker, then find the position of the ending marker (checking after your starting marker), then just grab the characters between that.

Comment: If you need to get string after *last* occurence of the symbol, you can use `strrpos`

Comment: If data comes from outside and is, for example, a numeric string, result is strange: 
`substr('456', strpos('456', "_") + 1)` gives `56`.

Answer (score 36):

`strtok` is an overlooked function for this sort of thing. It is meant to be quite fast.

```
$s = '233718_This_is_a_string';
$firstPart = strtok( $s, '_' );
$allTheRest = strtok( '' );
```

Empty string like this will force the rest of the string to be returned.

NB if there was nothing at all after the '_' you would get a `FALSE` value for `$allTheRest` which, as stated in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php), must be tested with ===, to distinguish from other falsy values.

Comment: Be careful: strtok will return the portion of the string *after* the character if it is the first character in the string, e.g., `strtok('a_b', '_')` will return `a` but `strtok('_b', '_')` will return `b`, not an empty string as you'd expect

Comment: Hmm re this comment, I think I wouldn't "expect" an empty string, I would probably *wonder whether* I was going to get an empty string...

Comment: My comment was an attempt to say that this answer will break if `_` is the first character. If `$s` in the code above is `"_This_is_a_string"` the result will be `is_a_string`, not `This_is_a_string`. Therefore, it is not a solution to _“How to get everything after a certain character?”_ for every case.

Answer (score 19):

Here is the method by using `explode`:

```
$text = explode('_', '233718_This_is_a_string', 2)[1]; // Returns This_is_a_string
```

or:

```
$text = end((explode('_', '233718_This_is_a_string', 2)));
```

By specifying `2` for the `limit` parameter in [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), it returns array with 2 maximum elements separated by the string delimiter. Returning 2nd element (`[1]`), will give the rest of string.

---

Here is another one-liner by using `strpos` (as suggested by [@flu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405493/how-to-everything-after-a-certain-character/45266494#comment44047446_11405509)):

```
$needle = '233718_This_is_a_string';
$text = substr($needle, (strpos($needle, '_') ?: -1) + 1); // Returns This_is_a_string
```

Comment: The silencer `@` is a bad coding practice. The error gets silenced, but the error keeps getting logged. Your disk will get full.

Answer (score 12):

I use strrchr(). For instance to find the extension of a file I use this function:

```
$string = 'filename.jpg';
$extension = strrchr( $string, '.'); //returns ".jpg"
```

Comment: $extension = substr(strrchr($string, '.'), 1); // returns "jpg"

Comment: @Pino do NOT mislead readers about the result of your script.  Your answer is incorrect.  You will need to call a second string function to remove the unwanted leading symbol.

Answer (score 5):

Another simple way, using [strchr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strchr.php) or [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
$str = '233718_This_is_a_string';

echo ltrim(strstr($str, '_'), '_'); // This_is_a_string
```

In your case maybe ltrim() alone will suffice:

```
echo ltrim($str, '0..9_'); // This_is_a_string
```

But only if the right part of the string (after _) does not start with numbers, otherwise it will also be trimmed.

Answer (score 3):

if anyone needs to extract the first part of the string then can try,

**Query:**

```
$s = "This_is_a_string_233718";

$text = $s."_".substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, "_"));
```

**Output:**

*This_is_a_string*

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "233718_This_is_a_string";
$withCharacter = strstr($string, '_'); // "_This_is_a_string"
echo substr($withCharacter, 1); // "This_is_a_string"
```

In a single statement it would be.

```
echo substr(strstr("233718_This_is_a_string", '_'), 1); // "This_is_a_string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this line to return the string after the symbol or return the original string if the character does not occur:

```php
$newString = substr($string, (strrpos($string, '_') ?: -1) +1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use single function calls over multiple function calls when possible.  I also prefer not to create a temporary array to access a string value (so `explode()` and `preg_match()` are less attractive IMO).  I would probably use `preg_replace()` in one of my own projects for stability, brevity, and maintainability (and because I am comfortable with regex).

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Vdbk8))

```
echo explode('_', $string, 2)[1]; // the limit parameter gives reliability
```

---

```
echo ltrim($string, '0..9_'); // because character after first underscore is not a digit or underscore
```

---

```
echo preg_match('/\d+_\K.+/', $string, $m) ? $m[0] : null;
```

---

```
echo preg_replace('/^\d+_/', '', $string);
```

---

```
echo sscanf($string, '%*d_%[^\d]')[0]; // because no numbers in trailing substring
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get everything after certain characters and if those characters are located at the beginning of the string, you can use an easier solution like this:

```
$value = substr( '123_String', strlen( '123_' ) );
echo $value; // String
```