# How to get string after a symbol

Tags: php

```
$data['subject']= "Languages > English"; 

//This is how I get the string before the symbol '>'.   
$subject = substr($data['subject'], 0, strpos($data['subject'], "> "));
```

But Now I need to get word after the '>' symbol. How do I alter the code above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get everything after a certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405493/get-everything-after-a-certain-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or using explode :

```
$array = explode(' > ', $data['subject']);
echo $array[0]; // Languages
echo $array[1]; // English
```

Comment: Or even `echo explode(" > ", $data['subject'])[1];`

Answer (score 4):

https://php.net/substr

```
$subject = substr($data['subject'], strpos($data['subject'], "> "));
```

But you should have a look at explode : https://php.net/explode

```
$levels = explode(" > ", $data['subject']);
$subject = $levels[0];
$language = $levels[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data before and after the >, I would use an explode.

```
$data['subject'] = "Languages > English";
$data['subject'] = array_map('trim', explode('>', $data['subject'])); // Explode data and trim all spaces 
echo $data['subject'][0].'<br />'; // Result: Languages
echo $data['subject'][1]; // Result: English
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way,

1. your string is converted in an array
2. then you keep the last value of your array

```
$data['subject']= "Languages > English";
$subject = end(explode('>',$data['subject']));
```