# How to echo domain tld from a domain

Tags: php, regex

I want to echo the domain tld such as .com or .net from any domain

althought I want to echo if this domain https or http

example : https://facebook.com

I want to echo com and https

example 2 : http://blockchain.info

I want to echo info and http

example 3 :http://www.sub.test.info

I want to echo info and http

I have tried this

```html
<?php

function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : $pieces['path'];
    
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}

echo get_domain("https://facebook.com");

?>
```

but this  echo facebook.com

edit: I want to echo domain tld and the https/http

Comment: i want to echo only the tld and https this question doesn't help me

Comment: protocol:RegExp.$2, tld: last element of RegExp.$3 split on '.'

Answer (score 0):

Use either [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to [check if it's http or https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php) and then use [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) along with [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to [get everything after the last dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405493/how-to-get-everything-after-a-certain-character).

Comment: can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
function get_specs($url){
   $pieces = parse_url($url);
   $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : $pieces['path'];
   $tld = end(explode(".", $pieces['host'])); 
   return array("tld"=>$tld,"protocol"=>$pieces["scheme"]);
}

var_dump(get_specs('http://www.example.sub.com/site'));

/*
 results 

    tld => com,
    protocol => http    

*/
```

Comment: how to echo only the $tld

Comment: this wil lnot work with https://names.co.uk