# strrchr strtok php not working (extract everything after id=

Tags: php, replace, strtok, strrchr

been on this for 2 hours now ...
`$string = "https://www.example.com/?id=fsdf29512590125Agajgenaemganheji";`
`$end = strrchr($string, 'id='); // should return "fsdf29512590125Agajgenaemganheji"`

`echo $end;`

only returns "i"

these work but not in larger url

`$s = "https://www.example.com/?id=fsdf29512590125Agajgenaemganheji";`

`$firstPart = strtok( $s, 'id=' );`

`echo $firstpart;`

tried also `'id\='`

[How to get everything after a certain character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405493/how-to-get-everything-after-a-certain-character)

return `id=` value without `id=`

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using explode, you can try this

```
$string = explode("id=", "https://www.example.com/?id=fsdf29512590125Agajgenaemganheji", 2);

//$string[0] is https://www.example.com/? 
//$string[1] is fsdf29512590125Agajgenaemganheji
$id = $string[1];
```

Comment: thank u it worked...... could u kindly assist me on my other question/. i tried to vote up it says i didnt have an enough rep.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610803/php-dom-document-table-extract-not-working-by-class-name

Comment: You can accept the answer , I will take a look on your other question

Comment: oh i just notivced that button i clickeed accapt thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the value of a parameter from a URL query string here, so you might as well use the functions that PHP explicitly provides for such purposes.

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/?id=fsdf29512590125Agajgenaemganheji";
$qs = parse_url($url)['query'];
parse_str($qs, $params);

var_dump($params['id']);
```