# Get numeric value between unique string and underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, text-extraction

Can someone tell me how to get "123" out of this string with regex:

> .../groups/123_abc/...

I am sure that

> /groups/

is unique in that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=groups\/)\d+
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/57

```
$re = "/(?<=groups\\/)\\d+/im";
$str = ".../groups/123_abc/...";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: So in PHP that would be preg_match('(?<=groups\/)\d+', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches); and then access the ID with $matches[0]?

Comment: The `m` modifier offers no benefit to regex patterns without `^` or `$` as start/end of string metacharacters.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever may be the language, you can split on `"/groups/"` and then take the second element, which is at index 1.

Then split on `_` and take the first element which is at index `0`.

Comment: @RaphaelJeger very well then. Just follow the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessarily using lookarounds in a regex pattern can lead to poor performance.

This task does not require any lookarounds.  Match the leading, literal `/groups/` subsrtring, then release it from the full string match using `\K`, then match the desired digits.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dum46))

```
$str = '.../groups/123_abc/...';

var_export(
    preg_match('#/groups/\K\d+#', $str, $m)
    ? $m[0]
    : null
);
```

If you use `explode()` as an alternative to the above script, you will need to remove the unwanted characters from element `[1]` using [a second technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77119679/2943403).