# How to strip and get the code between two lines in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, explode

I'm trying to assign it to a variable in PHP, but all the Regex and `preg_replace` I've tried doesn't help me. Here is a sample text.

```
Claim Code:
7241B-2HWRXR9-2P2BA
$1.00
```

I want to pull out exactly what is in the middle, which is `7241B-2HWRXR9-2P2BA`.

Comment: Idk man, it looks good to me? I didn't try it though but sure would have liked some reasoning for a downvote

Comment: possible duplicate of [get number in front of 'underscore' with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220998/get-number-in-front-of-underscore-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
Claim Code:\s*([\w-]+)\s*\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

And you can pull out whatt you want by `$1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rW0kZ5/1)

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant than a regexp / `preg_replace`, but this should work, too: Put the string into an array, then only use line 2 (array element number 1).

```
<?php
$string = 'Claim Code: ...............';
$lines = explode("\n", $string); //Transform the string into an array, separated by new lines (\n) (each index in the array is a single line from the string
echo $lines[1]; //this is 2nd line of the string, i.e. the claim code
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code has always the same format (5-7-5 chars), you can use:

```
$str = 'Claim Code:
7241B-2HWRXR9-2P2BA
    $1.00';

preg_match('~[\w]{5}\-[\w]{7}\-[\w]{5}~', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // returns 7241B-2HWRXR9-2P2BA
```

**UPDATE**
For optional code length this regex is possible:

```
preg_match('~.*:\s+([\w\-]{10,25})\s+.*~', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //       ^^ here set the min and max code length, or remove it 

// without setting min/max code length:
preg_match('~.*:\s+([\w\-]+)\s+.*~', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: works great, but sometimes it's not always 5-7-5... can you help me just grab everything in between `:` and `$` ?

Comment: @panther no need to escape `-` :)